# XSLT Dynamic Rows

Tags: xslt

I'm having an issue with the data being properly formatted. The top level node is Part. The elements below the node are AML and Documents. The AML and Documents can be different values. AML can be greater than Documents and Documents can be greater then AML. I need the elements for Documents and AML to be on the same row, so that the table is properly formatted. Please let me know if you need anymore information and thank you for your help its greatly appreciated.

Data

```
<Item type="Part">
    <item_number>E008643</item_number>
    <Relationships>
      <Item type="Part AML">
        <related_id keyed_name="0000-009" type="Manufacturer Part">
          <Item type="Manufacturer Part">
            <manufacturer keyed_name="Fasteners Co." type="Manufacturer"></manufacturer>
            <item_number>0000-009</item_number>
          </Item>
        </related_id>
        <state>Preliminary</state>
      </Item>
      <Item type="Part AML">
        <related_id keyed_name="1234" type="Manufacturer Part">
          <Item type="Manufacturer Part">
            <id keyed_name="1234" type="Manufacturer Part"></id>
            <manufacturer keyed_name="Vishay/Dale" type="Manufacturer"></manufacturer>
            <item_number>1234</item_number>
          </Item>
        </related_id>
        <state>Preliminary</state>
      </Item>
      <Item type="Part Document">
        <related_id keyed_name="D000006" type="Document">
          <Item type="Document">
            <id keyed_name="D000006" type="Document"></id>
            <major_rev>B</major_rev>
            <name>Hardware Doc</name>
            <item_number>D000006</item_number>
          </Item>
        </related_id>
      </Item>
      <Item type="Part Document">
        <related_id keyed_name="D000005" type="Document">
          <Item type="Document">
            <major_rev>B</major_rev>
            <name>Firmware</name>
            <item_number>D000005</item_number>
          </Item>
        </related_id>
      </Item>
      <Item type="Part Document">
        <related_id keyed_name="D000003" type="Document">
          <Item type="Document">
            <major_rev>A</major_rev>
            <name>Design Spec</name>
            <item_number>D000003</item_number>
          </Item>
        </related_id>
      </Item>
      <Item type="Part BOM">
        <related_id keyed_name="E000371" type="Part">
          <Item type="Part">
             <item_number>E000371</item_number>
            <Relationships>
              <Item type="Part AML">
                <related_id keyed_name="3Z1JTTD" type="Manufacturer Part">
                  <Item type="Manufacturer Part">
                    <manufacturer keyed_name="Speer" type="Manufacturer"></manufacturer>
                    <item_number>3Z1JTTD</item_number>
                  </Item>
                </related_id>
                <state>Preliminary</state>
              </Item>
              <Item type="Part AML">
                <related_id keyed_name="000T" type="Manufacturer Part">
                  <Item type="Manufacturer Part">
                    <manufacturer keyed_name="Nickel" type="Manufacturer"></manufacturer>
                    <item_number>000T</item_number>
                  </Item>
                </related_id>
                <source_id keyed_name="E000371" type="Part"></source_id>
                <state>Preliminary</state>
              </Item>
              <Item type="Part AML">
                <related_id keyed_name="R00V" type="Manufacturer Part">
                  <Item type="Manufacturer Part">
                    <manufacturer keyed_name="Sonic" type="Manufacturer"></manufacturer>
                    <item_number>R00V</item_number>
                  </Item>
                </related_id>
                <state>Preliminary</state>
              </Item>
              <Item type="Part AML">
                <related_id keyed_name="TRF" type="Manufacturer Part">
                  <Item type="Manufacturer Part">
                    <manufacturer keyed_name="Components" type="Manufacturer"></manufacturer>
                    <item_number>TRF</item_number>
                  </Item>
                </related_id>
                <state>Preliminary</state>
              </Item>
              <Item type="Part AML">
                <related_id keyed_name="70RL" type="Manufacturer Part">
                  <Item type="Manufacturer Part">
                    <manufacturer keyed_name="Comp" type="Manufacturer"></manufacturer>
                    <item_number>70RL</item_number>
                  </Item>
                </related_id>
                <state>Preliminary</state>
              </Item>
              <Item type="Part Document">
                <related_id keyed_name="D000007" type="Document">
                  <Item type="Document">
                    <major_rev>B</major_rev>
                    <name>BOX</name>
                    <item_number>D000007</item_number>
                  </Item>
                </related_id>
                <state is_null="1" />
              </Item>
              <Item type="Part Document">
                <related_id keyed_name="D000008" type="Document">
                  <Item type="Document">
                    <major_rev>A</major_rev>
                    <name>SOCKET</name>
                    <item_number>D000008</item_number>
                  </Item>
                </related_id>
                <state is_null="1" />
              </Item>
            </Relationships>
          </Item>
        </related_id>
      </Item>
</Relationships>
```

Style Sheet

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:aras="http://www.aras-corp.com" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
     <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="yes" indent="yes"></xsl:output>

     <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
          <head></head>
          <style type="text/css" userData="Global">
        table  {empty-cells:show; border-collapse:collapse;}
        th {font-family:helvetica; font-size:8pt;  padding:2px; border:1px #000000 solid; background-color:#CCCCCC; text-transform:capitalize;}
        td {font-family:helvetica; font-size:8pt;  padding:2px; border:1px #000000 solid;}
        td.noBorder {font-family:helvetica; font-size:8pt;  padding:2px; border-width:0;}
       </style>
          <body topmargin="50" leftmargin="50">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="1850">
              <tr valign="top">
                <td class="noBorder" align="left" colspan="9" uniqueID="ms__id39">
          </td>
         </tr>
              <tr valign="bottom">
                <td class="noBorder" colspan="13" style="font-family:helvetica;font-size:15pt;color:#DA1943;padding:2px;" align="left" uniqueID="ms__id22">Bill of Materials Report -              <xsl:value-of select="//Item/name"></xsl:value-of> Rev              <xsl:value-of select="//Item/major_rev"></xsl:value-of>
                </td>
                <td class="noBorder" colspan="7" style="font-family:helvetica;font-size:10pt;padding:2px;" align="right" uniqueID="ms__id23">Generated on:              <script>function m00(r, n){r += ""; if (!n) n = 2; while(r.length &lt; n){r = "0" + r;} return r;} var dt = new Date(); var a = top.opener.top.aras; if (a){var s = m00(dt.getUTCFullYear(),4)+"-"+m00((dt.getUTCMonth()+1))+"-"+m00(dt.getUTCDate())+"T"+m00(dt.getUTCHours())+":"+m00(dt.getUTCMinutes())+":"+m00(dt.getUTCSeconds())+"+0000"; s = a.convertToNeutral(s, "date", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"); s = a.convertFromNeutral(s, "date", "short_date"); document.write(s);}</script>
                </td>
         </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Part Number</th>
                <th>Manufacturer</th>
                <th>Manufacturer Part</th>
                <th>Document Number</th>
                <th>Document Name</th>
                <th>Document Rev</th>
           </tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//Item[@type='Part']"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
       </body>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
        </html>
     </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="Item[@type='Part']">

      <!-- Find the number Row Span -->
        <xsl:variable name="AML">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(Relationships/Item[@type='Part AML'])=0">1</xsl:when>        
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="count(Relationships/Item[@type='Part AML'])"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="Doc">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(Relationships/Item[@type='Part Document'])=0">1</xsl:when>        
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="count(Relationships/Item[@type='Part Document'])"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="rowCount">
         <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$AML &lt; $Doc"><xsl:value-of select="$Doc"></xsl:value-of></xsl:when> 
            <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$AML"></xsl:value-of>    
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>  
      </xsl:variable>

     <!-- Grab values -->
       <tr>
          <td rowspan="{$rowCount}" width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id16">
            <xsl:value-of select="item_number"></xsl:value-of>
          </td>      
          <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id26">
            <xsl:value-of select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part AML'][1]/related_id/Item/manufacturer/@keyed_name"></xsl:value-of>
          </td>
          <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id27">
            <xsl:value-of select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part AML'][1]/related_id/Item/item_number"></xsl:value-of>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id28">
            <xsl:value-of select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part Document'][1]/related_id/Item/item_number"></xsl:value-of>
          </td>
          <td width="13%px" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id29">
            <xsl:value-of select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part Document'][1]/related_id/Item/name"></xsl:value-of>
          </td>
          <td width="8%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id30">
            <xsl:value-of select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part Document'][1]/related_id/Item/major_rev"></xsl:value-of>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="{$rowCount}" width="8%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id37">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(Relationships/Item[@type='Part AML'])"></xsl:value-of>
          </td>
          <td  rowspan="{$rowCount}" width="8%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id38">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(Relationships/Item[@type='Part Document'])"></xsl:value-of>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="{$rowCount}" width="8%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id40">
            <xsl:value-of select="position() mod 2 = 1"></xsl:value-of>
          </td>
        </tr>

    <!-- Assing first row for AML and Doc -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part AML'][position()!=1]|Relationships/Item[@type='Part Document'][position()!=1]"></xsl:apply-templates>
     </xsl:template>

     <!-- AML and Doc Rows 2+ -->    
        <xsl:template match="text()" />

       <xsl:template match="Item[@type = 'Part AML'][not(following-sibling::Item[1]/@type = 'Part Document')]">
        <xsl:call-template name="ItemRow">
          <xsl:with-param name="AmlItem" select="." />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="Item[@type='Part Document']">
        <xsl:variable name="lastItem" select="preceding-sibling::Item[1][@type = 'Part AML']" />

        <xsl:call-template name="ItemRow">
          <xsl:with-param name="AmlItem" select="$lastItem" />
          <xsl:with-param name="PartDocument" select="." />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template name="ItemRow">
        <xsl:param name="AmlItem" />
        <xsl:param name="PartDocument" select="_" />

        <xsl:variable name="rowData">
          <row value="{$AmlItem/related_id/Item/manufacturer/@keyed_name}" id="32" />
          <row value="{$AmlItem/related_id/Item[@type='Manufacturer Part']/item_number}" id="33" />
          <row value="{$PartDocument/related_id[@type='Document']/Item/item_number}" id="34" />
          <row value="{$PartDocument/related_id[@type='Document']/Item/name}" id="35" />
          <row value="{$PartDocument/related_id[@type='Document']/Item/major_rev}" id="36" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($rowData)/row">
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id{@id}">
              <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
            </td>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output 1-7-12

```
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id32">Bobs Workshop</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id33">1234</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id34">D000005</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id35">Firmware</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id36">B</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id34">D000003</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id35">Design Spec</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id36">A</td>
```

Desired Output

```
 <!-- If both present -->
    <tr>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id32">Bobs Workshop</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id33">1234</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id34">D000005</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id35">Firmware</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id36">B</td>
    </tr>        
<!-- If only Doc is present -->
    <tr>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id32">""</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id33">""</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id34">D000003</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id35">Design Spec</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id36">A</td>
    </tr>   
<!-- If only AML is present -->
     <tr>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id32">Nickel</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id33">000T</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id34">""</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id35">""</td>
     <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id36">""</td>
    </tr>
```

Desired Full HTML Output

```
    <html xmlns:aras="http://www.aras-corp.com">
      <head>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16">
      </head>
      <style type="text/css" userData="Global">
        table  {empty-cells:show; border-collapse:collapse;}
        th {font-family:helvetica; font-size:8pt;  padding:2px; border:1px #000000 solid; background-color:#CCCCCC; text-transform:capitalize;}
        td {font-family:helvetica; font-size:8pt;  padding:2px; border:1px #000000 solid;}
        td.noBorder {font-family:helvetica; font-size:8pt;  padding:2px; border-width:0;}
       </style>
      <body topmargin="50" leftmargin="50">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="1850">
          <tr valign="top">
          </tr>
          <tr valign="bottom">
            <td class="noBorder" colspan="13" style="font-family:helvetica;font-size:15pt;color:#DA1943;padding:2px;" align="left" uniqueID="ms__id22">Bill of Materials Report -             9.6 Hz Parts Rev              1</td>
            <td class="noBorder" colspan="7" style="font-family:helvetica;font-size:10pt;padding:2px;" align="right" uniqueID="ms__id23">Generated on:              <script>function m00(r, n){r += ""; if (!n) n = 2; while(r.length < n){r = "0" + r;} return r;} var dt = new Date(); var a = top.opener.top.aras; if (a){var s = m00(dt.getUTCFullYear(),4)+"-"+m00((dt.getUTCMonth()+1))+"-"+m00(dt.getUTCDate())+"T"+m00(dt.getUTCHours())+":"+m00(dt.getUTCMinutes())+":"+m00(dt.getUTCSeconds())+"+0000"; s = a.convertToNeutral(s, "date", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"); s = a.convertFromNeutral(s, "date", "short_date"); document.write(s);}</script></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="6">Indenture Level</th>
            <th>Part Number</th>
            <th>Legacy Part Number</th>
            <th>Revision</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Parameters</th>
            <th>RoHS/Pb-Free</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Reference Designator</th>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Manufacturer Part</th>
            <th>Document Number</th>
            <th>Document Name</th>
            <th>Document Rev</th>
            <th>Pos AML</th>
            <th>Pos Doc</th>
            <th>Mod</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id10">0</td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id11"></td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id12"></td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id13"></td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id14"></td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id15"></td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id16">E008643</td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id17"></td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id18">1</td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id19">9.6 Hz Parts</td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id20">Test</td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id21">Assembly</td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id22"></td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id23">1</td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24"></td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id26">Fasteners Co.</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id27">009</td>
            <td width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id28">D000006</td>
            <td width="13%px" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id29">Hardware Doc</td>
            <td width="8%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id30">B</td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="8%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id37">2</td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="8%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id38">3</td>
            <td rowspan="3" width="8%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id40">true</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id32">Vishay/Dale</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id33">1234</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id34">D000005</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id35">Firmware</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id36">B</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id32"></td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id33"></td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id34">D000003</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id35">Design Spec</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id36">A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="5" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id10"></td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id11">1</td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id12"></td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id13"></td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id14"></td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id15"></td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id16">E000371</td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id17">0061</td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id18">A</td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id19">0?</td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id20">Thick Film ''</td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id21">0, 100, 0.05</td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id22">Yes</td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id23">1</td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">R34</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id26">Speer</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id27">RK73Z1JTTD</td>
            <td width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id28">D000010</td>
            <td width="13%px" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id29">BOX</td>
            <td width="8%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id30">B</td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="8%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id37">5</td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="8%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id38">3</td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="8%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id40">false</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id32">Nickel</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id33">000T</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id34">D000011</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id35">SOCKET</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id36">A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id32">Sonic</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id33">R00V</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id34">D000007</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id35">MOUNT</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id36">A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id32">NIC</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id33">OTRF</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id34"></td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id35"></td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id36"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id32">Test</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id33">9874</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id34"></td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id35"></td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id36"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id10"></td>
            <td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id11">1</td>
            <td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id12"></td>
            <td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id13"></td>
            <td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id14"></td>
            <td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id15"></td>
            <td rowspan="2" width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id16">E001163</td>
            <td rowspan="2" width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id17">0145</td>
            <td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id18">A</td>
            <td rowspan="2" width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id19">8200</td>
            <td rowspan="2" width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id20">PPS Film ''</td>
            <td rowspan="2" width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id21">
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2" width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id22">Yes</td>
            <td rowspan="2" width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id23">30</td>
            <td rowspan="2" width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">C1-C5,C12,C17,C22,C25,C27-C29,C31</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id26">Sonic</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id27">822GX5</td>
            <td width="5%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id28">D000012</td>
            <td width="13%px" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id29">Doc Test</td>
            <td width="8%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id30">A</td>
            <td rowspan="2" width="8%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id37">2</td>
            <td rowspan="2" width="8%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id38">2</td>
            <td rowspan="2" width="8%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id40">true</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id32"></td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id33"></td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id34">D000008</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id35">ADAPTER</td>
            <td width="13%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id36">A</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What XSLT processor are you using?

I believe this should do what you want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:aras="http://www.aras-corp.com" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="yes" indent="yes"></xsl:output>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <style type="text/css" userData="Global">
        table  {empty-cells:show; border-collapse:collapse;}
        th {font-family:helvetica; font-size:8pt;  padding:2px; border:1px #000000 solid; background-color:#CCCCCC; text-transform:capitalize;}
        td {font-family:helvetica; font-size:8pt;  padding:2px; border:1px #000000 solid;}
        td.noBorder {font-family:helvetica; font-size:8pt;  padding:2px; border-width:0;}
      </style>
      <body topmargin="50" leftmargin="50">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="1850">
          <tr valign="top">
            <td class="noBorder" align="left" colspan="9" uniqueID="ms__id39">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="bottom">
            <td class="noBorder" colspan="13" style="font-family:helvetica;font-size:15pt;color:#DA1943;padding:2px;" align="left" uniqueID="ms__id22">
              Bill of Materials Report -              <xsl:value-of select="//Item/name"></xsl:value-of> Rev              <xsl:value-of select="//Item/major_rev"></xsl:value-of>
            </td>
            <td class="noBorder" colspan="7" style="font-family:helvetica;font-size:10pt;padding:2px;" align="right" uniqueID="ms__id23">
              Generated on:              <script>function m00(r, n){r += ""; if (!n) n = 2; while(r.length &lt; n){r = "0" + r;} return r;} var dt = new Date(); var a = top.opener.top.aras; if (a){var s = m00(dt.getUTCFullYear(),4)+"-"+m00((dt.getUTCMonth()+1))+"-"+m00(dt.getUTCDate())+"T"+m00(dt.getUTCHours())+":"+m00(dt.getUTCMinutes())+":"+m00(dt.getUTCSeconds())+"+0000"; s = a.convertToNeutral(s, "date", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"); s = a.convertFromNeutral(s, "date", "short_date"); document.write(s);}</script>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th width="12%" colspan="6">Indent Level</th>
            <th width="5%">Part Number</th>
            <th width="13%">Manufacturer</th>
            <th width="13%">Manufacturer Part</th>
            <th width="13%">Document Number</th>
            <th width="13%">Document Name</th>
            <th width="13%">Document Rev</th>
            <th width="8%">Pos AML</th>
            <th width="8%">Pos Doc</th>
            <th width="8%">Mod</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//Item[@type='Part']"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
      </body>
      <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
      <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
      <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
      <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Item[@type='Part']">

    <xsl:variable name="AmlItems" select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part AML']"/>
    <xsl:variable name="DocItems" select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part Document']"/>

    <xsl:variable name="MoreAmlItems" select="count($AmlItems) > count($DocItems)" />

    <xsl:variable name="largerGroup" select="$AmlItems[$MoreAmlItems] | $DocItems[not($MoreAmlItems)]" />

    <!-- Ensure rowCount is at least 1 -->
    <xsl:variable name="rowCount" select="count($largerGroup) + (count($largerGroup) = 0)"/>

    <!-- Grab values -->
    <tr>
      <xsl:call-template name="IndentLevel">
        <xsl:with-param name="rowSpan" select="$rowCount" />
      </xsl:call-template>
      <td rowspan="{$rowCount}" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id16">
        <xsl:value-of select="item_number"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$largerGroup[1]" />
      <td rowspan="{$rowCount}" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id37">
        <xsl:value-of select="count($AmlItems)"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
      <td  rowspan="{$rowCount}" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id38">
        <xsl:value-of select="count($DocItems)"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="{$rowCount}" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id40">
        <xsl:value-of select="position() mod 2 = 1"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <!-- Assing first row for AML and Doc -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$largerGroup[position() > 1]"></xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="IndentLevel">
    <xsl:param name="level" select="0" />
    <xsl:param name="rowSpan" />

    <td rowspan="{$rowSpan}" width="2%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id{10+$level}">
      <xsl:if test="count(ancestor::Item[@type = 'Part']) = $level">
        <xsl:value-of select="$level"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </td>
    <!-- Stop when we reach 5 -->
    <xsl:if test="$level &lt; 5">
      <xsl:call-template name="IndentLevel">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="rowSpan" select="$rowSpan" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- AML and Doc Rows 2+ -->
  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <xsl:template match="Item[@type = 'Part AML']">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
    <xsl:variable name="isTop" select="not(preceding-sibling::Item[@type = 'Part AML'])"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="ItemRow">
      <xsl:with-param name="AmlItem" select="." />
      <xsl:with-param name="PartDocument" select="../Item[@type = 'Part Document'][position() = $pos + not($isTop)]" />
      <xsl:with-param name="IsTop" select="$isTop" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Item[@type='Part Document']">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
    <xsl:variable name="isTop" select="not(preceding-sibling::Item[@type = 'Part Document'])"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="ItemRow">
      <xsl:with-param name="AmlItem" select="../Item[@type = 'Part AML'][position() = $pos + not($isTop)]" />
      <xsl:with-param name="PartDocument" select="." />
      <xsl:with-param name="IsTop" select="$isTop" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="ItemRow">
    <xsl:param name="AmlItem" />
    <xsl:param name="PartDocument" select="_" />
    <xsl:param name="IsTop" />

    <xsl:variable name="startingId" select="26 * $IsTop + 32 * not($IsTop)" />

    <xsl:variable name="rowData">
      <cell value="{$AmlItem/related_id/Item/manufacturer/@keyed_name}" />
      <cell value="{$AmlItem/related_id/Item[@type='Manufacturer Part']/item_number}" />
      <cell value="{$PartDocument/related_id[@type='Document']/Item/item_number}" />
      <cell value="{$PartDocument/related_id[@type='Document']/Item/name}" />
      <cell value="{$PartDocument/related_id[@type='Document']/Item/major_rev}" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="rowCells">
      <xsl:call-template name="RowCells">
        <xsl:with-param name="rowData" select="$rowData" />
        <xsl:with-param name="startingId" select="$startingId" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$IsTop">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$rowCells"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <tr>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$rowCells"/>
        </tr>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="RowCells">
    <xsl:param name="rowData" />
    <xsl:param name="startingId" />

    <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($rowData)/cell">
      <td align="center" uniqueID="ms__id{$startingId + position() - 1}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
      </td>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you're using a non-Microsoft XSLT processor, you would need to change the msxsl namespace to something else according to the table on this page:
http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html

There seems to be an inconsistency between your source XML and your output.  The `<related_id>` in the first Item has no `type` attribute, so your [@type='Manufacturer Part'] filter would fail to locate anything.  Is there supposed to be a `type` attribute there?

Comment: JLRishe thank you for your help I really appreciate it. This works really well for Documents. I uploaded more information to show the whole picture. I'm working with Microsoft XSLT. The way I was trying to solve it in the past I needed to identify the Manufacture Part so it grabbed the right item_number. Currently it looks like its not getting any AML data if there is more then one AML element in the tree. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, so you would like the following: Part AML without a Part Document immediately after - show just the Part AML info; Part AML with a Part Document immediately after - show both together; Part Document without a Part AML immediately before - show just the Part Document info. Is that everything?  If so, please try the above (modified).

Comment: If both AML and Document are present, I would like them on the same row. Other then that its perfect. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I was just getting ready to put something like this together with the sibling matching but this is much cleaner than what I had. +1

Comment: @user1618044 Re: your last comment, isn't that what I described here?: Part AML with a Part Document immediately after - show both together

Comment: I was looking at the output and they are in separate rows. Do I have something setup wrong in my sytle sheet? I copied and pasted this strait into my style sheet.

Comment: Added the output above. There are some rows that have both, and some that have just one or the other.  The ones that have just one or the other occur because there were two AMLs or two Documents in a row.  Are you expecting a different result?

Comment: I think the reason it's not working with your full XSL is that it's using this to call the Item templates: `<xsl:apply-templates select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part AML'][position()!=1]|Relationships/Item[@type='Part Document'][position()!=1]"></xsl:apply-templates>`.  What's the purpose for the `position() != 1` there??

Comment: It also looks like there's other stuff in your XSL creating rows with 8 cells.  Is it supposed to be that way?

Comment: Ok. When I remove the position()!=1 I get the correct results. I got this code from the from the people that created the software. They only had AML in the style sheet. My company wants the documents to also be included. I believe its used so it only selects the second elements and down. If you look just above the position()!=1, you can see that its grabbing the first Doc and AML. Should I change that? I need this to end up in a grid view. Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example of the full HTML that you would like it to produce for the table?  Even after removing the `position() != 1`, the rendered table still looks cockeyed.

Comment: I just added the full HTML table. I added some extra data. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks.  I can have a look at this a while from now.  Where do the id17-id24 values come from?  I don't see the value "9.6 Hz Parts" or "PPS Film ''" anywhere in the source XML.

Comment: I just uploaded the information that needed to by dynamic. It all comes from Part. Its on the same level as Part/Item Number. It also gets treated the exact same as item number. Do you want me to add that extra data?

Comment: No that's ok.  Once I've finished the XSLT you can probably figure out the rest.

Comment: XSL updated.  Give it a try.  Except for the Indentation part, I've left out the extra columns that weren't already in the XSLT, since I reckon you can figure that part out. I moved the column widths out to the table header since they were complicating the logic and the having them in the header should have the same net effect with less clutter. I hope that's alright.

Answer (score 0):

In your first template I would change it like this.

```
<xsl:template match="Item[@type='Part AML']|Item[@type='Part Document']">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="related_id/Item/manufacturer/@keyed_name"/>
    ...
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

That should build out your rows like you want.

Comment: Matthew, Thank you for your help. Its now entering a row between id_33 and id_34. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: It looks like that is being caused by the `match` for your `template`. I'm going to have to look closer at this. How do you determine which `Part AML` goes with which `Part Document`.

Comment: They are random. It all depends on the part. Some parts have an AML (approved manufacture part) and documents. Some only have AML and some only have documents. So that's where most of my trouble has been with how dynamic it has to be. The full tree looks like Item[@type='Part']/Relationship/Item[@type='Part AML']. Would you want me to post the whole style sheet or more data? Thanks